# ios why can't i hook WKCustomProtocol methods

Tags: ios, iphone, runtime

WKCustomProtocol is a class form WebKit [source code](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebKit/NetworkProcess/CustomProtocols/Cocoa/LegacyCustomProtocolManagerCocoa.mm)， I've already debugged it. It exists

HDWebURLProtocol，WKCustomProtocol superClass is NSURLProtocol. I hook my own class 'HDWebURLProtocol', which was successful, But WKCustomProtocol was not successful;

I use Xcode 10.1, iOS 12.1 simulator， Debug run [WebKit code](https://github.com/harddog/webkit.git)

This is My Code:

```html
+ (void)exchange {

    Class WKCustomProtocolClass = object_getClass(NSClassFromString(@"WKCustomProtocol")); // HDWebURLProtocol

    SEL canInitWithRequest = NSSelectorFromString(@"canInitWithRequest:");
    SEL af_canInitWithRequest = NSSelectorFromString(@"fix_canInitWithRequest:");

    BOOL add1 = class_addMethod(WKCustomProtocolClass,
                                canInitWithRequest,
                                class_getMethodImplementation(WKCustomProtocolClass, canInitWithRequest),
                                "B@:@");

    BOOL add2 = class_addMethod(WKCustomProtocolClass,
                                af_canInitWithRequest,
                                (IMP)af_canInitWithRequest2,
                                "B@:@");

    NSLog(@"%d,%d", add1, add2);

    Method orgi = class_getClassMethod(WKCustomProtocolClass, canInitWithRequest);
    Method after = class_getClassMethod(WKCustomProtocolClass, af_canInitWithRequest);

    method_exchangeImplementations(orgi, after);
}

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"

BOOL af_canInitWithRequest2(id sender, SEL cmd, NSURLRequest *req) {
    SEL canInitWithRequest = NSSelectorFromString(@"fix_canInitWithRequest:");
    return [sender performSelector:canInitWithRequest withObject:req];
}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

[breakpoint screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLJSq.png)